# Why cant i use apk package manager in my Gitlab pipeline?

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline, alpine-linux

Im trying to build a pipeline which ssh's into my server, and executes a bash script. But when i execute the pipeline, it states: `bash: line 129: apk: command not found`
Why though? Im already specifying to use alpine over my default node image

My runner is configured as a shell executor

```
image: node:16

build:
    only:
        - main
    script:
        - docker build --file Dockerfile --tag $IMAGE_NAME .

push_to_dockerhub:
    only:
        - main
    script:
        - docker login --username $DOCKERHUB_USERNAME --password $DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD
        - docker push $IMAGE_NAME

deploy:
    image: alpine:3.14
    only:
        - main
    before_script:
        - apk add openssh-client
        - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
        - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
        - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
        - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    script:
        - ssh myusername@$IP_ADDRESS -p 3000 "/home/myusername/deploy.sh && exit"
```

I need to be able to use apk on this pipeline to add the openssh client and therefore, stablish an ssh connection

Comment: Can u just confirm whether the runner you are using is a docker executor. If so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The NodeJS default version you get from docker hub's is a **Debian-based** distribution. Therefore, `apt` or `apt-get` must be used as a package management tool.

You must use an **alpine-based** Node container if you want to use `apk` (Alpine Package Keeper).

Example `image: node:lts-alpine`

The NodeJS docker container is built using a variety of versions and underlying Linux distribution. Please click the [link](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/tags?page=1) to view them, then select what you require based on your requirements.